# How do I make apple script tell running python script to run a function?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, applescript

macOS AppleScript has the ability to 'tell' running apps like safari to do something, like open a tab.

How do I add an AppleScript compatible api to my python application?

*such that applescripts can interact with my running script.*

Comment: this seems to talk around the idea:  https://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/AppleScript
still looking for a specific example.

Comment: https://tidbits.com/2019/06/25/apple-to-deprecate-scripting-languages-in-future-versions-of-macos/ I may be wrong, and I'm not sure if it applies to Applescript, but I understood Apple were deprecating some/all/most scripting languages...

Answer (score 0):

Native AppleScript can send basic messages to applications: i.e., processes the system can identify with a bundle id. It can't send messages to other running processes (aside from the standard signals that can be sent to processes in unix). Since you've apparently bundled this script as an application, you ought to be able to send it basic commands like `open` or `quit`.

From a quick glance at the wiki you linked in comments, it seems that you can install Apple Event Handlers using an implementation of primitive carbon methods, using the low-level Carbon.AE extension, and that (in theory) should allow AppleScript to talk to your process in more complex ways: AppleScript uses Apple Events to communicate. Further, if you've installed the PyObjC packages you can (probably) use higher-level Objective-C commands to install AE handlers, or even to load a scripting definition file. that would allow you to define scripting objects and scripting commands that others could access through AppleScript. It's reasonably easy to do this in ObjC, but I wouldn't call it trivial, and transcribing it into a PyObjC implementation would add a number of warts and wrinkles.